# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure() in ~/src/bootstrap/app.php

Tags: laravel-5, omnipay

I try to use OmniPay in my Laravel 5.2 project by adding the following line in my composer.json

```
"ignited/laravel-omnipay": "2.*",
"lokielse/omnipay-alipay": "dev-master"
```

Then after I add the following line in bootstrap/app.php line 46,

```
$app->configure('laravel-omnipay');
```

and create a new controller, I hit error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure() in /home/xxx/src/bootstrap/app.php on line 46
```

Any idea will be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
$app->configure('laravel-omnipay');
```

Is for installation in Lumen.

For Laravel follow only this section:
[laravel-omnipay laravel-5 Installation](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay#laravel-5)

Comment: I see. I missed the title. Let me try without this and the register.